# Add WebPart to page and lock it down (except for editing)

Tags: 2010, web-part, page-layout, publishing-page

I'm building out some features for a publishing portal for a client, and I have a requirement to place a Content Editor Webpart on a page and prevent users from deleting, closing, hiding, or moving it.  They must only be able to edit the content.

This is really a multi-part question. What's the best approach, and how do I get it to work?

1. I tried adding the web part directly to a custom page layout - and the web part renders, but is uneditable.  Is there a way to do this and have it be editable?
2. I'm currently trying to add the web part to the page layout inside a webpart zone and set properties to achieve the desired access:

   <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server">
     <ZoneTemplate>
       <WebPartPages:ContentEditorWebPart>
         <WebPart>
           <!-- blah blah -->
           <AllowEdit>true</AllowEdit>
           <AllowRemove>false</AllowRemove>
           <AllowClose>false</AllowClose>
           <!-- etc -->
         </WebPart>
       </WebPartPages:ContentEditorWebPart>
     </ZoneTemplate>
   </WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
3. Right now I'm still building out the page layout using designer, but ultimately it will be deployed as a module feature.  Another approach I've seen is to leave the page layout empty but to add the webpart using the `AllUsersWebPart` element to configure the webpart when the feature is enabled.  I haven't tried this yet, and it sure would be nice if I could get this to work before I get there because if I have to do it that way, my "compile-edit-test" cycle sure does get long and tedious.

Comment: If you are using publishing pages, what's the rationale for using a content editor webpart? Sounds to me like you would be better off with the publishing content controls instead.

Comment: @PaulLucas to which controls are you referring?

Comment: Assuming you are using the publishing features of SP2010 (page layouts/content types etc), http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms551164.aspx

Comment: Yeah, ok.  That may wind up being the answer.  A RichHtmlField is certainly simpler than trying to deploy and restrict a webpart.

Comment: Ok... I'll give you a proper answer then :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, if you are working with the SharePoint publishing infratructure to create a content managed site, you should be looking more at leveraging the Publishing Field Controls for editing content, rather than content editor web parts.

The following article provides a good understanding of the differences between the two; while it was written for SP2007, most of the info is still relevant to SP2010.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd571480(v=office.12).aspx